# Can I use Swift 3 in Xcode 7?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode7, swift3

Can I use **Swift 3** in **Xcode 7**, and if the answer is "Yes", then how?

Comment: [No](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=36).

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is: No, you cannot use Swift 3 in Xcode 7.

A [simple Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=swift+3+xcode+7) shows us that:

- [Xcode 7 introduced support for Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode-Archive/Articles/xcode_7_0.html)
- [Xcode 8 introduced support for Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
- [The migration process from 2.2 to 2.3 or 3.0 requires Xcode 8](https://swift.org/migration-guide/)

### Why?

Xcode contains not just the nifty visual IDE for you to build iOS, tvOS, watchOS, and macOS applications, but it also provides the Swift compiler. Because the compiler is built-in to Xcode, you can't simply have your old Xcode do new tricks. The new Xcode provides new features that Swift 3 supports and, to some extent, requires.

If you are an app developer looking to get into Swift 3, enroll in the [Apple Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/). Once enrolled, you'll be able to download the beta of Xcode 8 for free and write Swift 3 code there.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry but I really bad in search in English, sorry again

Comment: @Prince it's okay. Gotta start somewhere! Just in the future be sure to show *any* attempt you made to answer your own question. Some people on this site would not be so kind as I. :)

Comment: FWIW That "simple Google search" returns this question as the first response.

Comment: @AnthonyW Ha! That amuses me more than I can express here, haha